# How to do complete border on excel using OpenXml in C#?

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

[Excel document demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhDe2.png)

I want to make a complete border on Excel using OpenXml. Able to a particular column but not able to do the complete. Please review.

Comment: You could try this out, helped me many times.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/releases/tag/v2.5

Comment: Create a blank Excel document that contains the border you desire. Open that file in the productivity tool and then click reflect code. It will then give you the C# code that is required to produce that border.